# How can I get author-year references in footnotes? (I.e. Harvard style but in footnotes, rather than in parentheses in the text)

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, apa-style

I'm trying to configure `biblatex` to work so that I get Author-Year references in footnotes rather than in the bulk of the text.

So what I want is:

> Previous literature has suggested* and this is tue.
>
> *Bloggs, 2010, p. 10

I am currently using `biblatex` with the `apa` style. If there is a simple command to make this appear in footnotes (without having to include titles and publishing info) then it'd be great to know!

Comment: `biblatex` provides the `\footcite` command, which does as you ask.